# Best way to get machine id on Linux?

Tags: linux, unique, gnu, uniqueidentifier

What is the best-practiced way to get an unique machine ID in `GNU/Linux` for `i386` architecture?

Are there any good ways except the `mac` address?

Comment: The mac address is not guaranteed to be unique, as it can be changed

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Depending on your kernel, the DMI information may be available via sysfs.
Try those:

```
# cat /sys/class/dmi/id/board_serial
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

or using a tool

```
# dmidecode -s baseboard-serial-number
...
# dmidecode -s system-uuid
...
```

Comment: While googling about the `/sys/class/dmi/id/board_serial` availability I have found http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/ids.html

Comment: So, actually, I will use `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id`.

Comment: That doesn't seem so portable, depending on dbus and all.

Comment: That's very x86 specific. There is no such thing as `/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid` on Linux PPC (Apple based) for example.

Comment: Is machine-id useful for licensing beside mac?

Comment: `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` can be changed with sudo

Comment: Which one will stay the same after the os is reinstalled?

Comment: Reading from `/sys` is not guaranteed as they may be 0600 and owned by root, same for running dmidecode

Answer (score 33):

On modern machines with systemd: machine id is created by [systemd-machine-id-setup](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-machine-id-setup.html#). The location of machine id is documented - in [freedesktop machine-id](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html) and [man machine-id](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/machine-id.5.html) and machine id has a more standardized format - [see RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122). Just:

```
cat /etc/machine-id
```

Comment: the machine-id may be the same on cloned VMs.

Comment: But isn't that the whole idea of having a "cloned VM"  of begin the same machine-id. 
Here the VM software seems to be the real problem as a clone is a to simplified command without specifying what the clone is used for.

Comment: @pynexj On LPIC 1 preparation courses you learn that there are 3 things to change after cloning a machine: MAC addresses, ssh host keys and the DBUS machine ID. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use lshal. This needs hal (apt-get install hal or yum install hal) to be installed first. This way you can access all the info of dmidecode without root permissions.

**A non-root equivalent of**

```
# dmidecode | grep -i uuid
```

**will be**

```
$ lshal |grep -i system.hardware.uuid
```

And similarly other info as per your needs.

Comment: If `lshal` is available on said system, this means `hal` is installed, which means `dbus` is installed. Therefore it is simply `cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id`

Comment: @malat it is clear from the question that user wants to generate a uuid which is permanent and doesn't change. "dbus/machine-id" can even change after every reboot.

Comment: Is machine-id useful for licensing beside mac?

Answer (score 0):

A simple and portable way of computing your own sysid may be to serialize uname(), gethostid() and some inodes like /home or your application homedir (obtained with stat()) etc. in a string and hash It.