# Use System.Management to get UUID in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, system.management

I am working on a .NET Core application. My requirement is that i have to get the UUID of motherboard. Code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string uuid = string.Empty;

    ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystemProduct");
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        uuid = mo.Properties["UUID"].Value.ToString();
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("UUID : " + uuid);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This code works perfectly fine on windows machine but when i move to the linux machine, i get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Management currently is only supported for Windows desktop applications.                                                                             
at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
at System.Management.ManagementObject..ctor()
at System.Management.ManagementClass..ctor(String path)
at uniqueSystemId.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Is **System.Management** not supported for linux ? If not, how can i get the UUID of motherboard on both linux and windows machine

Comment: You are trying to use a Win32 specific API on Linux, it's not surprising it doesn't work.  Does Linux even have a UUID?

Comment: agreed. How can i solve this problem ? @Neil

Comment: You are probably going to have to delve into /proc or /dev, and it's unlikely there is some existing code to do it, so you are going to have to write it yourself.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152762/best-way-to-get-machine-id-on-linux

Comment: Yes. Bascically start programming and do not rely on WMI (which System.Management accesses) - Windows (<-) Management Instrumentation. And you saw that you create a Win32 (Windows 32) API object in it? ;) 10 seconds in google ("linux get motherboard uuid") made this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152762/best-way-to-get-machine-id-on-linux - telling you how to read the UUIS on linux. Which is a lot easier than on windows actually.

Comment: @TomTom thanks for the answer. Actually the command in the answer of the link you have mentioned requires authentication, my requirement is that i can not ask user to end the password, i have to find the UUID without any user interaction. So, basically i am asking, is there any way that i can do it with "System.Management" or any other better approach ?

Comment: Nope. No way. System.Management ALSO requires authentication, except it will in a domain automatically use your account.

Comment: thanks for information, much appreciated @TomTom