# system-uuid on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: c, linux, uuid

I got a question.

That is I want to retrieve a system uuid to generate an identity. But I found that root privilege is needed if I execute command `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid`.Just same as `dmidecode -s system-uuid`，Someone tell me that I can install `lshal`. But I don't want to install it. Because code will not work if others computer didn't install `lshal`.
So I want to get `product_uuid` without root privilege.

Comment: `retrieve a system uuid` ? There is no such thing as "system uuid' - usually such thing is _generated_ from other things, like network interface mac address. `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_name` that file for me just has motherboard name, bad choose for "system uuid". `Someone tell me that I can install lshal` ? Sure why not, i'll tell you. "You can install lshal".

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my question, which I mean is `product_uuid` instead of `product_name`.

Comment: I have added an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63148464/9072753 , cause I _guess_ that you got your information from there. Does it answer your question?

Comment: I know that. But the result of `cat /etc/machine-id` is different from `sudo cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid`

Comment: ? Why does it matter?

Comment: @OnlyThen: As an user, I do not want programs to have free access to immutable identifiable information they can use to fingerprint *me*.  Systemd uses `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` for exactly this purpose, and I actually dislike that too – but at least I can change it if I want to.  So, the true question is, *what do you need an immutable machine identifier for*?  If the answer includes *"licensing"*, use a licensing server with certificates, instead of playing willy-nilly with immutable user-identifying information.

Comment: Yeah, You are right. But I just want to do a C implementation of this [Project](https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation/blob/master/lib/system.js). In it's system.js. They use `product_uuid`, And I want to implement it by my self. Just all.